# Query to find all the nodes that are two steps away from a particular node

Tags: sql-server, graph

Suppose I have two columns in a table that represents a graph, the first column is a FROMNODE
and second one is TONODE.
What I would like to know is that how will we find all the nodes that are two steps away from a particular node.
Lets suppose I have a node numbered '1' and i would like to know all the nodes that are two steps away from it.

I have tried (I am assuming the table name as graph)

```
SELECT FROMNODE FROM GRAPH WHERE TONODE=1
```

This is to select all the nodes that are connected to node 1, but I couldn't figure out how would I find all the nodes that are two steps away from node 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take it one step at a time!

```
select step2.tonode
from   graph step1
join   graph step2 on step2.fromnode = step1.tonode
where  step1.fromnode = 1
```

Comment: thanks for the response.....but, this gives 1 as one of the output node, which couldn't be possible, as we are starting from node 1 and looking at all the other nodes that are connected to node 1 and are two steps away from node 1.
Lets say if 2 and 3 are connected to node 1 and 4,5 are connected to node 2....... 8,9 are connected to node 3.....then we have to find 4,5,8,9 as they are two steps away from node 1.

Answer (score 0):

Join back onto the same table...

```
SELECT g2.FromNode
FROM Graph as g1 
JOIN Graph as g2 ON g2.ToNode = g1.FromNode
WHERE g1.ToNode = @startnode
;
```